# No me funciona la función While para limitar entradas

Tags: c++, while

Estoy realizando pruebas con C++ tras 7 años sin programar, para reanudar un poco esto, pero a la hora de limitar la entrada de datos mediante el bucle while, me encuentro que no acepta ningún valor permitido y continúa pidiéndome que ingrese un valor permitido. Se que se podría hacer con un bucle if o un swicth, pero he querido ir probando de todo. Disculpad si es un poco tontería la pregunta. Dejo un código de muestra.

#include 
using namespace std;

int main() {

```
char x;

cout<<"Number: ";cin>>x;

if(x!='S'||x!='s'||x!='N'||x!='n'){
    do{
        cout<<"NOPE: ";cin>>x;
    }while(x!='N'||x!='n'||x!='S'||x!='s');
}else{
    cout<<"OK"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo es cuestión de repasar un poco la lógica.

Supon que ingresas 'S'.

```
x!='S'||x!='s'||x!='N'||x!='n'
```

x es igual a **S**. Pero x no es igual a **s** ni a **N** o **n**.

Estás uniendo las condiciones con `||` (or) por lo tanto al cumplirse al menos una de las condiciones, el resultado será verdadero.

En cambio, si usas `&&` (and), todas las condiciones deben cumplirse para que el resultado sea verdadero.

Bastará con usar:

```
x!='S' && x!='s' && x!='N' && x!='n'
```

O por teorema de Morgan, esta expresión es equivalente:

```
x=='S' || x=='s' || x=='N'|| x=='n'
```